# How to always show searchBar when viewController is loaded in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to show searchBar always visible that is in the navigation bar. Below UISearchController there are tableView/collectionView with mutliple cells. Now searchBar is not shown always, rather it is shown after scrolling the collectionView.

SearchBar in the navigationBar is expected to show always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in **Swift 5.2** or above

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

Comment: This solution only works if you use collectionView list cell and the search bar gets hidden initially but shows when you scroll down.